# Socket.io receiving and sending data

Tags: python, socket.io

I have this server made using socket.io As I listen to an event, I receive some data through this. Also, I want to emit another event that passes the same data to the socketIO-client file. But I'm unable to do that. Any suggestions?

//snippet of server.js file

```
socket.on('chatmsg_to_server',function(data) {
        console.log("msg from user: ");
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('msg_from_node',data);
        });
```

And on the client end, I have this code made using socketIO-client
//code snippet of client.py file

```
def doSomething(data):
    print "Halloween"
    
    if data in ['hey','hello']:
        socketIO.emit('reply_from_client',"hello clienty")
    print "hello client"


 socketIO.on('msg_from_node', doSomething)
```

but the problem is that the control doesn't even enter this function doSomething. How do I do it?

Comment: Did you figure it out yet